# Inject service with different configuration into controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dryioc

In a Web API application, I have two controllers, MyAController and MyBController, each depending on IMyService but with a different configuration:

```
public class MyAController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMyService service;
    public MyAController(IMyService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}

public class MyBController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMyService service;
    public MyBController(IMyService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}

public interface IMyService
{
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly string configuration;
    public MyService(string configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

I've tried configuring DryIoc the following way:

```
private enum ServiceKeyEnum
{
    ServiceA,
    ServiceB
}

container.RegisterInstance("configurationA", serviceKey: "CONFIGURATIONA");
container.RegisterInstance("configurationB", serviceKey: "CONFIGURATIONB");
container.Register<IMyService, MyService>(Reuse.Singleton, Made.Of(() => new MyService(Arg.Of<string>("CONFIGURATIONA"))), serviceKey: ServiceKeyEnum.ServiceA);
container.Register<IMyService, MyService>(Reuse.Singleton, Made.Of(() => new MyService(Arg.Of<string>("CONFIGURATIONB"))), serviceKey: ServiceKeyEnum.ServiceB);

container.Register<MyAController>(Reuse.InResolutionScope, made: Parameters.Of.Details((r, p) => ServiceDetails.IfUnresolvedReturnDefault).Type<IMyService>(serviceKey: ServiceKeyEnum.ServiceA));
container.Register<MyBController>(Reuse.InResolutionScope, made: Parameters.Of.Details((r, p) => ServiceDetails.IfUnresolvedReturnDefault).Type<IMyService>(serviceKey: ServiceKeyEnum.ServiceB));
```

and if I try to call resolve using:

```
var controllerA = container.Resolve<MyAController>();
var controllerB = container.Resolve<MyBController>();
```

I get two controllers configured with configurationA and configurationB respectively.
However, when I try to call the api using a REST call, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyAController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

so I guess, that I need to register the controller in a different way... but how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you configured Web API to use DryIoC? https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.WebApi/

Comment: Why controllers registered with Reuse.InResolutionScope instead of InWebRequest? When resolving them directly it effictively makes them Transient.

Comment: Yes, WebAPI is configured with container.WithWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); I've tried both InWebRequest, InResolutionScope, .... without any success

Comment: Given that controllers discovered and registered as a batch (via DryIoc.WebApi) you cannot specify individual registrations.  But you may put control back to IMyService to decide where to inject itself: `c.Register<IMyService, MyService>(Made.Of(() => new MyService(Arg.Index<string>(0)), configA),  Reuse.Singleton, setup: Setup.With(condition:  r => r.ImplementationType == typeof(MyAController))) `
the similar for MyBController.  Here you can avoid using service keys,  plus no need to register configs.

Comment: InResolutionScope won't work anyway. DI. WebApi register controllers InWebRequest. InWebRequest actually is a sugar for `InCurrentNamedScope(Reuse. WebRequestScopeName)`.  You may test the controller resolutions inside `using(var scope = container.OpenScope(Reuse.WebRequestName) {  scope.Resolve controllers here } `

Comment: Tried to replace all the above registration with just: container.Register<IMyService, MyService>(Made.Of(() => new MyService(Arg.Index<string>(0)), _ => "configurationA"), Reuse.Singleton, setup: Setup.With(condition: r => r.ImplementationType == typeof(MyAController)));
container.Register<IMyService, MyService>(Made.Of(() => new MyService(Arg.Index<string>(0)), _ => "configurationB"), Reuse.Singleton, setup: Setup.With(condition: r => r.ImplementationType == typeof(MyBController)));

Comment: but I still get an error when calling my api: "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyAController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."

Comment: Changed it to: Setup.With(condition: r => r.Parent.ImplementationType == typeof(MyAController)) and now it seems to work

Comment: Sorry,  it was my mistake to omit Parent in condition.  Glad you still tryed it and it work.  I guess the original problem cause was the DryIoc was unable to resolve controller,  then WebApi fallback to creating controller using parameterless ctor,  hence the error. I will put the complete answer to help in similar situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by improper setup for controllers.  The DryIoc.WebApi extension have already discovered and registered your controllers,  so normally you don't need to do it yourself.  I will provide the working code (from the question comments) for you specific setup later.  But now the reason behind the "parameterless constructor..": when DryIoc fails, WebAPI falls back to using `Activator.CreateInstance` for controller, which expects parameterless constructor. The fallback masks the original DryIoc error. To find it, you can setup DryIoc.WebApi extension as:

```
container = container.WithWebApi(throwIfUnresolved: type => type.IsController());
```

The working setup for your case,  which registers dependencies with condition to select controller for injection:

```
container.Register<IMyService, MyService>(Made.Of(
    () => new MyService(Arg.Index<string>(0)), _ => "configurationA"),  
    Reuse.Singleton, 
    setup: Setup.With(condition:  r => r.Parent.ImplementationType == typeof(MyAController)));

container.Register<IMyService, MyService>(Made.Of(
    () => new MyService(Arg.Index<string>(0)), _ => "configurationB"),  
    Reuse.Singleton, 
    setup: Setup.With(condition:  r => r.Parent.ImplementationType == typeof(MyBController)));
```

The main thing that this setup does not require special controller registration.

Plus you can avoid using service keys, and no need to register config strings separately.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the Setup.With Condition, really a nice way to handle it.